# Magento 2.1.1 Add to Cart message stuck

Tags: magento2, cart

I have just completed a new installation and have noticed that the "Add to Cart" message is appearing on every page. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, however, we should remove local storage and session.

Comment: I am using Redis. Could it have something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been reported to Magento

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6686